# How to design for 3.2" and 4.7" Android screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I need help with designing layout for Android devices. I have these layout folders:

- layout-small
- layout-large
- layout-xlarge

But problem is because it seems that I must use same dimensions for layouts with 3.2 inch and for layouts with 4.7 inch.

Is there way to seperate these stuff? Because layout with dimension for 3.2 inche screen can't look good on 4.7 inch screen. As you can see frome the pictures below, on 4.7 inch screen there is a lot of empty space.

**3.2 inch Android screen**

[image]

**4.65 inch Android screen**

[image]

Comment: "Because layout with dimension for 3.2 inche screen can't look good on 4.7 inch screen" -- yes, it can. "As you can see frome the pictures below, on 4.7 inch screen there is a lot of empty space" -- center your layout vertically.

Comment: So, what I got a layout on the center with empty space on the top of layout.

Comment: Correct. You are welcome to come up with a GUI design that handles this better, by taking advantage of the space, if this concerns you. Since the empty space will only be a couple of millimeters, users may be less concerned than you are. To draw an analogy, you act as though it is impossible to have a Web site that can look good at different browser window sizes.

Comment: Okey, empty spaces isn't that a big problem. But, anyway size of these number buttons should be bigger on 4.7, because that will provide better user expirience, and fix that problem with empty space. :) So, I am asking you, is there way to use differente dimension values for this?

Comment: You shoudn't be using dimension values in the first place. Use `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight`.

Comment: Thank you, this fix this problem. Anyway, if you want you may write an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want to avoid using dimensions for widget sizes. There will be cases when it is unavoidable, or even advisable, but it is difficult to create "fluid" layouts that way.

If you want widgets that take up a certain percentage of the screen, use `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight`, using the weights to allocate the available space:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/fifty_percent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:text="@string/thirty_percent"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="@string/twenty_percent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```